# AngularJS : Write HTML Output to textfile

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cordova, output

I'm working on an AngularJS 1.5 project with PhoneGap. 
Now I would like to write the HTML output to a textfile.

I was trying to use the innerHTML function, but this returns the wrong output, example this return:

```
<html>
  <body>Hi {{ Name }}</body>
</html>
```

What I really want to save:

```
<html>
  <body>Hi Developer</body>
</html>
```

Does someone has the solution?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a bit more complicated than what it seems at first glance. Angular does not have some sort of output buffering you simply can get a hold of. Your best bet will be to to save the rendered markup using your browser. In Firefox you can use `View Source » View Generated Source`. In Chrome you find a similar option under the tools menu.

Or if you want to go down the code road, here is a response from one of the [Angular devs, *Misko Hevery*](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/kHKZ93pmb14):

> We have not done this, but if you feel up to it here is what you can
>   try
>
> - get node.js running
> - install of the many DOM implementations for node
> - Get your angular page running inside the node.js.
> - Get a hold of the $browser service and call `notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests()` this will    tell you when the
>     page finished rendering
> - Do document.html() to get    rendered HTML
>
> [...]

Comment: Thanks for answer. 

The only problem is that I'm using PhoneGap in my project. So I can't use the above solution. I would like to save the html to generate a PDF of the page...

Comment: And what about computed CSS styles? How to save them together with html?

Answer (score 0):

If you're actually using angular then you should be able to use `innerHTML` after the binding is done.  ([*fiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/pBdpa/))

```
<div ng:controller="CombinedCtrl" id="combined">
    X: {{x}}, Y: {{y}}
    <button ng-click="showHtml()">Show HTML</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
    $scope.showHtml = function() {
        alert('HTML IS:\r\n' + document.getElementById('combined').innerHTML);
    };
```